Dropwizard Hibernate Inject Session Factory into DAO using Guice
I have the dropwizard setup similar to this guide: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/hibernate.html
private final HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration>(Person.class) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);
}

@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration config, Environment environment) {
    final PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
    environment.jersey().register(new UserResource(dao));
}

Instead of constructing new PersonDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory()), I would like to use guice Dependency Injection. how do I @Provides a sessionFactory to make PersonDAO injectable?
I've tried creating a HibernateModule, but I'm getting concurrency issues:
public class HibernateModule  extends DropwizardAwareModule<ExampleConfiguration> {
    private final HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration>(Person.class) {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bootstrap().addBundle(hibernate);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws Exception {
        hibernate.run(configuration(), environment());
        return hibernate.getSessionFactory();
    }
}


Calling hibernate.run(configuration(), environment()); is not allowed, it's modifying the configured bundles as it's looping through it.
package io.dropwizard.core.setup;
public class Bootstrap<T extends Configuration> {
    public void run(T configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        for (ConfiguredBundle<? super T> bundle : configuredBundles) {
            bundle.run(configuration, environment);
        }
    }
}

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
    at io.dropwizard.core.setup.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:198)
    at io.dropwizard.core.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:65)
    at io.dropwizard.core.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:98)
    at io.dropwizard.core.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.core.Application.run(Application.java:94)


I assume you are using dropwizard-guicey for guice integration (according to code). Then there is a complete hibernate integration example project
Don't mix dropwizard bundles and guice modules initialization: their lifecycles are different (guice module would be processed under dropwizard run phase). Let dropwizard manage bundle, and provide only required instance to guice:
public class HibernateModule extends AbstractModule {

    private final HibernateBundle hbnBundle;

    public HibernateModule(HibernateBundle hbnBundle) {
        this.hbnBundle = hbnBundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(SessionFactory.class).toProvider(hbnBundle::getSessionFactory);
    }
}

Note: bind(SessionFactory.class).toProvider(hbnBundle::getSessionFactory); could be implemented as provider method (as in your case)
It is important to register hiberante bundle before guice bundle:
private final HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration>(Person.class) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);
    bootstrap.addBundle(GuiceBundle.builder()
         .modules(new HibernateModule(hibernate))
         .extensions(UserResource.class) // if classpath scan not enabled
         .build());
}

@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration config, Environment environment) {
   // nothing here!    
}

Now we can simply inject session factory into dao:
@Singleton
public class PersonDAO {
   @Inject
   private Provider<SessionFactory> factory;
}

There is no need to declare PersonDAO anywhere, just inject it in resource:
public class UserResource {
   @Inject
   private PersonDAO dao;
}

